# No space after image when image is centered

Tags: html, css

On my website, when I center an image which has text after, the space between image and text disappear.

**No align, space exists:**
[image]

**Align center, space disappear:**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post images. It is impossible for us to help you with what you provided. It could be anything. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @disinfor In this case the images serve to illustrate the problem. What's missing here is the HTML and CSS

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular yeah, I know why the images were posted - I should have been more clear to say "do not **only** post images".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a margin issue, make sure the `div` that contains the image + text has the correct `margin-bottom` when you add the **Align center**

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!